# transpose query varchar bigint conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, transpose

I have the following sql query (this is a transpose query to get comma separated table)

```
    SELECT CAST ((SELECT taxonomy_id + ','
                  FROM content
                  FOR XML PATH('')) AS bigint) AS NewTaxonomytableName
```

But I am getting `Error converting data type varchar to bigint.`
The table `taxonomy_id` is a `bigint`

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
SELECT CAST ((SELECT CAST(taxonomy_id AS varchar) + ',' AS Expr1 FROM taxonomy_item_tbl FOR XML PATH('')) AS varchar) AS Expr1
```

Running this gives me one row.

But in fact it is not right for me. It needs to comma separate only the taxonomy_id's for a specific content_id.

An example:

```
content_id taxonomy_id
1          15 
1          16 
5          24 
5          19
```

needs to be:

```
content_id taxonomy_id
1          15,16
5          24,19
```

I am really stuck with this for 8 hours. If anyone can help me I will really appreciate it...

Thanks

Comment: You're casting the Comma Separated List to BIGINT.  But `'1,2,3,4'` can't be cast to a BIGINT...  CAST to NVARCHAR(max) or something instead?  Or just don't CAST it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't converting `taxonomy_id` to a bigint, you're converting a comma-seperated list of them to a bigint.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT CAST ((SELECT CAST(taxonomy_id as varchar) + ','
              FROM content
              FOR XML PATH('')) AS varchar(max)) AS NewTaxonomytableName
```

---

**EDIT**
Ok, since I'm not exactly certain of your table structure, you might need to play around with this to get exactly what you want, but the theory is right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.content_id,
    CAST((SELECT CAST(taxonomy_id as varchar) + ','
          FROM content
          WHERE content_id = c.content_id
          FOR XML PATH('')) AS varchar(max)) AS taxonomy_ids
FROM content c
```

Comment: Try now - I think you would have been getting a slightly different error: `Error converting data type bigint to varchar.` as opposed to `Error converting data type varchar to bigint.`

Comment: Break it down and check your data. My starting diagnostic would be does `SELECT CAST(taxonomy_id as varchar) + ',' FROM content` return any rows?

Comment: Ok, then how about `SELECT CAST(taxonomy_id as varchar) + ',' FROM content FOR XML PATH('')`?

Comment: I ran following `SELECT        CAST
                             ((SELECT        CAST(taxonomy_id AS varchar) + ',' AS Expr1
                                 FROM            taxonomy_item_tbl FOR XML PATH('')) AS varchar) AS Expr1` But I only get one row now?

Comment: @Ozkan - Yes that is to be expected. One row with all `taxonomy_id` concatenated.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson Hi, but I want to wrap all taxonomy_id of each content_id to one content_id (one row per content_id)

Comment: @Ozkan - How should we know that. You have not mentioned any of this in your question. Pleas update your question with table structures some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson Hi, I updated the topic. Please help me with this. I have an headache of thinking for a solution... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table
(
  content_id int,
  taxonomy_id int
)

insert into @T values
(1,          15), 
(1,          16), 
(5,          24), 
(5,          19)


select T1.content_id,
       stuff((select ','+cast(T2.taxonomy_id as varchar(20))
              from @T as T2       
              where T1.content_id = T2.content_id
              for xml path(''),  type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as taxeconomy_id
from @T as T1
group by T1.content_id
```

Result:

```
content_id  taxeconomy_id
----------- -------------
1           15,16
5           24,19
```